# Blockchain.info: Which address should I give for "New Shared Address"?

Tags: blockchain, address, money

I am new to Blockchain.info's wallet's features.

I clicked the "Receive Money" tab, then clicked "Shared" and then the green button labeled "New Shared Address". It gave me the following:

```
Address       Forward to      Expires in
abcdefg       123456          3 days
```

Which address should I give to my friend so that he will send the funds to a shared wallet of my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one marked "Address". It will forward it to the one marked "Forward To".

Comment: Thanks very much for your clarification. Blockchain.info's help section should have been more detailed.